# does Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED called for MMS?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I know how to use intent filter for

> android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

but my question is does this work for MMS??

Comment: hey , if it was useful for you then mark it as Accept, so that it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using below code in my Manifest to monitor SMS/MMS

**for SMS it is:**

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483645">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

**for MMS it is:**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

nopes, for MMS following line use `RECEIVE_MMS`

Comment: I can't find any intent filter for that action "android.provider.Telephony.RECEIVE_MMS"